# I am getting an Attribute error message when I want to make my sprite character shoot bullets. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am able to load my pygame window but when I press the space button to make my sprite character shoot it exits the pygame window and gives me an attribute error. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem? I have tried from bullet import Bullet but that does not work. Please help me fix this error so I can keep on coding...Would appreciate the help a lot.

autopilot.py code:

```
import pygame
import car
import debris

pygame.init()

#screen settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#fps
FPS = 120
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#load images
bg = pygame.image.load('background/street.png').convert_alpha() # background

#define game variables


######################CAR/DEBRIS##########################

player = car.Player(1, 5)
debris = debris.Debris(1, 5)

##########################################################

#groups
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
debris_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

debris_group.add(debris)

#game runs here
run = True
while run:

    #draw street
    screen.blit(bg, [0, 0])

    #update groups
    bullet_group.update()
    bullet_group.draw(screen)

    #draw debris
    debris.draw()

    #draw car
    player.draw()
    player.move()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        #check if key is down
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                run = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movingLeft = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movingRight = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                player.shoot()

        #check if key is up
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                player.movingLeft = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                player.movingRight = False

    #update the display
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

car.py code:

```
import pygame

#screen settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#load bullets
bullets = pygame.image.load('car/bullet.png').convert_alpha()

#groups
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

#player class
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.speed = speed
        #self.x = x
        #self.y = y
        self.moving = True
        self.frame = 0
        self.flip = False
        self.direction = 0

        #load car
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load('car/car.png').convert_alpha()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width()) * scale, (int(img.get_height()) * scale)))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.update_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.movingLeft = False
        self.movingRight = False
        self.rect.x = 465
        self.rect.y = 325

    #draw car to screen
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery))

    #move car
    def move(self):
        #reset the movement variables
        dx = 0
        dy = 0

        #moving variables
        if self.movingLeft and self.rect.x > 33:
            dx -= self.speed
            self.flip = True
            self.direction = -1
        if self.movingRight and self.rect.x < 900:
            dx += self.speed
            self.flip = False
            self.direction = 1

        #update rectangle position
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

    #shoot
    def shoot(self):
        bullet = bullets.Bullet(self.rect.centerx + 18, self.rect.y + 30, self.direction)
        bullet_group.add(bullet)
```

bullet.py code:

```
import pygame
from autopilot import debris, bullet_group

#screen settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#load bullets
bullets = pygame.image.load('car/bullet.png').convert_alpha()

#bullet class
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, direction):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.speed = 5
        self.image = bullets
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x,y)
        self.direction = direction

    def update(self):
        self.rect.centery -= self.speed
        #check if bullet has gone off screen
        if self.rect.top < 1:
            self.kill()
        #check collision with cement block
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(debris, bullet_group, False):
            if debris.alive:
                debris.health -= 25
```

debris.py code:

```
import pygame

#screen settings
WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("AutoPilot")
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

#debris class
class Debris(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, scale, speed):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.x = 400
        self.y = HEIGHT / 2 - 200
        self.speed = speed
        self.vy = 0
        self.on_ground = True
        self.move = True
        self.health = 100
        self.max_health = self.health
        self.alive = True

        #load debris
        self.images = []
        img = pygame.image.load('debris/cement.png').convert_alpha()
        img = pygame.transform.scale(img, (int(img.get_width()) * scale, (int(img.get_height()) * scale)))
        self.images.append(img)
        self.image = self.images[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    #draw debris to screen
    def draw(self):
        screen.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
```

My error:

[image: Error message]

Comment: The line `bullet = bullets.Bullet(...` looks like it should be `bullet = bullet.Bullet`, you are trying to pull in the Bullet class from the bullet module, but instead it is accessing the module variable bullets. You need to import the bullet module into car. Use another name for clarity to avoid clashing with the module name, e.g. `bullet_ = bullet.Bullet(...`, or indeed `from bullet import Bullet`

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the error. Paste the error trace.

Comment: `from bullet import Bullet` and `bullet = Bullet(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an instance of the class `Bullet`. Therefore you must import `Bullet`:

```py
from bullet import Bullet
```

Finally you can use the class `Bullet`:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx + 18, self.rect.y + 30, self.direction)
        bullet_group.add(bullet)
```

---

If you just want to import the *bullet.py* file, you have to rename the `bullet` variable. Otherwise there will be a name conflict between the variable `bullet` and the module `bullet`:

```py
import bullet
```

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def shoot(self):
        bullet_object = bullet.Bullet(self.rect.centerx + 18, self.rect.y + 30, self.direction)
        bullet_group.add(bullet_object)
```